# Documentation of the ehcache statistics API in 2.8.x

Tags: java, statistics, migration, ehcache

Somewhere between 2.6.x and 2.8.x ehcache seems to have completely changed their statistics API.

Is there any documentation available for this change?

**A little background**

I'm trying to migrate [metrics ehcache instrumentation](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/issues/615) to ehcache 2.8.3, which basically means [fixing this class](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/9919b0f52cd79a13cdf385cbb9fddf088c4e5552/metrics-ehcache/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/ehcache/InstrumentedEhcache.java).

I think I managed to guess many of the changes, but I'm totally lost how to replace the following calls in 2.8.x

```
cache.setSampledStatisticsEnabled(true);
cache.setStatisticsAccuracy(Statistics.STATISTICS_ACCURACY_NONE);
cache.getStatistics().getStatisticsAccuracyDescription();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those methods don't have equivalents in the new statistics API.  They would map to no-ops.  The new statistics API turns on statistics as you access them.  There isn't really any explicit enable or disable.  If you stop using a statistic it gets disabled after a user configurable time (Time-To-Disable).  All statistics are accurate, and the more statistics you use (or the more complicated the statistics) the more overhead you get.  Hope that makes sense!

[Source: I'm the co-author of the new statistics api/impl]